# Invalid or unexpected token referencing HTML in JS

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

Code:

```
    (function () {

var itemCtx = {};
itemCtx.Templates = {};

itemCtx.Templates.Header = “<div><b>Announcements</b></div><table>”; <---syntax error here?
itemCtx.Templates.Item = ItemOverrideFun;
itemCtx.Templates.Footer = “</table>”; <---syntax error here?

itemCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
itemCtx.ListTemplateType = 104;

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(itemCtx);

})();

function ItemOverrideFun(ctx) {

var _announcementTitle = ctx.CurrentItem.Title;

var _announcementDesc = ctx.CurrentItem.Body;

var _announcementID = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;

return “<tr><td><p><b>” + _announcementTitle + “</b></p>” + _announcementDesc +”<a href=’/Lists/Company%20Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=’+ _announcementID +’> Read More…</a></td></tr>”; <---syntax error here?
}
```

When this code is called the Chrome console says there's a invalid or unexpected token syntax error.

The error displays on lines with the double quotes and in the Chrome console the double quotes are actually replaced with icons that look like diamonds with question marks in them.

So far I've tried swapping them with single quotes and encasing the double quotes in single quotes, neither has worked.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Replace `“` with `"`**

As the error message shown in the console, there is clearly an error in the `“` that you are using. The `“` that you are using is not the same as `"` that is to be used.

Thus, replace all the occurences of `“` with `"`.

`“` is `LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK` and `"` is `QUOTATION MARK` . You should understand that
 both are different.

Check [this](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%E2%80%9C) for `“` and see [this](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%22) for `"`.

Answer (score 1):

Lal made a good point. I've fixed it below.

Here:

```
 (function () {

var itemCtx = {};
itemCtx.Templates = {};

itemCtx.Templates.Header = "<div><b>Announcements</b></div><table>";
itemCtx.Templates.Item = ItemOverrideFun;
itemCtx.Templates.Footer = "</table>";

itemCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
itemCtx.ListTemplateType = 104;

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(itemCtx);

})();

function ItemOverrideFun(ctx) {

var _announcementTitle = ctx.CurrentItem.Title;

var _announcementDesc = ctx.CurrentItem.Body;

var _announcementID = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;

return "<tr><td><p><b>" + _announcementTitle + "</b></p>" + _announcementDesc +"<a href='/Lists/Company%20Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=" _announcementID +"'> Read More…</a></td></tr>";
```

This was the problem:

```
”<a href=’/Lists/Company%20Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=’+ _announcementID +’>
```

You had tried to close the string with the single quote, you needed a double to close it before you concatenated `_announcementID`

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace all the single quotes and double quotes with the proper characters then quote the other fragment of the link properly with the double quotes: `_announcementID+"'> Read More...</a>`

```
(function () {

var itemCtx = {};
itemCtx.Templates = {};

itemCtx.Templates.Header = "<div><b>Announcements</b></div><table>";
itemCtx.Templates.Item = ItemOverrideFun;
itemCtx.Templates.Footer = "</table>";

itemCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
itemCtx.ListTemplateType = 104;

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(itemCtx);

})();

function ItemOverrideFun(ctx) {

var _announcementTitle = ctx.CurrentItem.Title;

var _announcementDesc = ctx.CurrentItem.Body;

var _announcementID = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;

return "<tr><td><p><b>" + _announcementTitle + "</b></p>" + _announcementDesc +"<a href='/Lists/Company%20Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID="+ _announcementID+"'> Read More...</a></td></tr>";
}
```